# Windows logs DCOM error (ID 10028) even though remote connection to IIS works fine in code

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, dcom

We have a Windows service that checks whether an IIS site or application pool is running. The service can check IIS sites on both the local server as well as remote servers. The service is written in C#/.NET 6 and it uses the ServerManager class in the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace to do the checking.

The service works as expected. It receives accurate information about the IIS sites it checks. No problems there.

However, despite that, every time the service checks an IIS site on a remote server, the systems logs a DistributedCOM error (event ID 10028) to the System Event Log: "DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer XXX using any of the configured protocols."

Neither I nor my colleague have managed to find anything that would explain this error. I'm baffled, since from my point of view as a coder, everything works fine.

Any idea what might be causing the issue and what to do about it? The server is a Windows Server 2016.

Comment: It looks like the connection was made, but not with any of the "Configured Protocols".  See : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/dcom-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer/m-p/1760463?force_isolation=true and https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2157207-windows-dc-dns-error-on-dcom-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer-8-8-8-8?force_isolation=true